# PHP $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] returning wrong value

Tags: php

When I access the index page of my site, I get the right value for `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`:

URL: http://pro.ovh.net/~xyz/mySiteName

```
$scriptName = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
var_dump($scriptName);
```

prints expected value:

> /~xyz/mySiteName/index.php

BUT if I access another page, like for example: http://pro.ovh.net/~xyz/mySiteName/about

prints:

> /mySiteName/index.php

"~xyz" part of the URL has disappeared, why?

PS: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` return the same results

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: fixing a part of the code of my MVC framework that detects the baseUrl for a site. It only bugs for these kind of temporary URLs above. Code is the following:
$requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$scriptName = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$baseUrl = implode('/', array_filter(array_intersect_assoc($requestURI, $scriptName)));

Comment: Are you using Apache? If you are, how do you load PHP? As a module, or with `mod_fgcid`? If you're using `mod_fcgid`, make sure `FcgidFixPathinfo` is set to 0 in your `httpd.conf`. I had [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265469/php-serverscript-name-is-wrong-when-loading-php-via-mod-fcgid), and that's how I fixed it.