# PHP $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is wrong when loading PHP via mod_fcgid

Tags: php, apache, mod-fcgid

I'm using Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.7.

I have a `test.php` file in `C:\web\vhosts\Symfony\web`.

The value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is correct:

```
C:/web/vhosts/Symfony/web/test.php
```

However the value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` depends on how I load PHP:

---

**If I load PHP as an Apache module**, the value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is:

```
/test.php
```

I'm a bit surprised that it isn't the same as `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, but at least it's a correct value, I guess.

Here's how I loaded PHP:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/web/php-5.5.7-Win32-VC11-x86/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php 
PHPIniDir "C:/web/php-5.5.7-Win32-VC11-x86"
```

---

**If I load PHP using mod_fcgid**, the value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is:

```
C:/test.php
```

Which is just wrong...

Here's how I loaded PHP (based on [a tutorial from ApacheLounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=2394)):

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so 

<IfModule fcgid_module> 
   FcgidIOTimeout 40 
   FcgidConnectTimeout 10 

   FcgidMaxProcesses 300 
   FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 300 

   FcgidOutputBufferSize 64 
   ProcessLifeTime 0 
   FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 0 
   FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0 
   FcgidFixPathinfo 1 
   FcgidProcessLifeTime 0 
   FcgidZombieScanInterval 20 
   FcgidMaxRequestLen 536870912 
   FcgidIOTimeout 120 
   FcgidTimeScore 3 

   FcgidPassHeader Authorization 

   FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:\\web\\php-5.5.7-Win32-VC11-x86" 
   FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:\\web\\php-5.5.7-Win32-VC11-x86;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;" 
   FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:\\Windows" 
   FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:" 
   FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP" 
   FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP" 
   FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:\\WINDOWS" 
   <Files ~ "\.php$"> 
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php 
      FcgidWrapper "C:/web/php-5.5.7-Win32-VC11-x86/php-cgi.exe" .php 
   </Files> 
</IfModule>
```

What's wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I know what's wrong:

```
FcgidFixPathinfo 1
```

Set this value to 0. You can also comment it out, or remove it altogether, since 0 is the default.

---

According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidfixpathinfo):

> This directive enables special SCRIPT_NAME processing which allows PHP to provide additional path information. The setting of FcgidFixPathinfo should mirror the cgi.fix_pathinfo setting in php.ini.

However I found that the value of `cgi.fix_pathinfo` in the `php.ini` file makes absolutely no influence as to the value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`:

- When `FcgidFixPathinfo` is set to `0` in the `httpd.conf` file, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is correct (`/test.php`), regardless of the value of `cgi.fix_pathinfo` in the `php.ini` file.
- When `FcgidFixPathinfo` is set to `1` in the `httpd.conf` file, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is incorrect (`C:/test.php`), regardless of the value of `cgi.fix_pathinfo` in the `php.ini` file.